# techniques to track NLP as time series

Tags: deep-learning, nlp

I have the following use-case (toy/example, not the actual usecase) for sentiment classification. I have respondents (`userid`) who at random intervals, write some `comments` about how he/she feels. The goal is to classify the sentiments (Positive/negative) based on comments and see if the pattern is going towards positive or negative.

```
userid| time            | comment
1     | jan 1, 11:00 am | cccccsccscccscsc
1     | jan 1,  3:00 pm | dddddddddddd
1     | jan 2, 10.00 am | cccccsccscccscsc
1     | jan 2,  5:00 pm | dddddddddddd
2     | jan 1, 11.00 am | cccccsccscccscsc
2     | jan 1,  3:00 pm | dddddddddddd
2     | jan 1, 11.00 pm | ccccssssssc
2     | jan 2,  9:00 am | dddddddddddd
2     | jan 2,  3:00 pm | dddddddddddd
2     | jan 3, 10.00 am | ccccssssssc
2     | jan 3,  2:00 pm | dddddddddddd
2     | jan 3,  5.00 pm | cccccsccscccscsc
2     | jan 3,  9:00 pm | dddddddddddd
```

Sentiment classification algorithm can deal with this problem, but it will not take into account the time-series. These algorithm will consider each row independent from another rows.
I am exploring if any method/code exist to solve these kind of problem. Here we want to look at the sequence of NLP text in sequence and decide if the sentiment is positive or negative.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking a look at the methodology introduced in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.05321.pdf) on converting time to vector (Time2vec). The time vector is learned from the time stamp T(t) corresponding to the input comment. Once you obtain the representations associated with a single column, you can sum up the representation with the time vector (specific to that comment), and process them through the output linear layer to learn the sentiment class/rating.